# Recursive function is not following all paths

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, recursion, logic

I've been involved to a challenge.

Here is the question given:

> This question involves a game with teddy bears. The game starts when I
>   give you some bears. You can then give back some bears, but you must
>   follow these rules (where n is the number of bears that you have):
>
> If n is even, then you may give back exactly n/2 bears. If n is
>   divisible by 3 or 4, then you may multiply the last two digits of n
>   and give back this many bears. (By the way, the last digit of n is
>   n%10, and the next-to-last digit is ((n%100)/10). If n is divisible by
>   5, then you may give back exactly 42 bears. The goal of the game is to
>   end up with EXACTLY 42 bears.
>
> For example, suppose that you start with
>   250 bears. Then you could make these moves:
>
> --Start with 250 bears.
>
> --Since 250 is divisible by 5, you may return 42 of the bears, leaving you with 208 bears.
>
> --Since 208 is even, you may return half of the bears, leaving you with 104 bears.
>
> --Since 104 is even, you may return half of the bears, leaving you with 52 bears.
>
> --Since 52 is divisible by 4, you may multiply the last two digits (resulting in 10) and return these 10 bears. This leaves you with 42
>   bears.
>
> --You have reached the goal!
>
> **Write a recursive function to meet this specification:**

`bool bears(int n)
   // Postcondition: A true return value means that it is possible to win
   // the bear game by starting with n bears. A false return value means that
   // it is not possible to win the bear game by starting with n bears.
   // Examples:
   //   bear(250) is true (as shown above)
   //   bear(42) is true
   //   bear(84) is true
   //   bear(53) is false
   //   bear(41) is false`

> Hint: To test whether n is even, use the expression ((n % 2) == 0).

**Here is my solution** but unfortinately it always returns false. I guess it is not following the whole alternative paths but have no idea why. Btw, i'm very new with the VB. Thanks in advance.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(bear(Int(TextBox1.Text)))
    End Sub
    Public Function bear(bc As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim way1, way2, way3 As Integer
        If bc = 42 Then
            Return True
        ElseIf bc < 42 Then
            Return False
        ElseIf (bc Mod 2 = 0) Or (bc Mod 3 = 0) Or (bc Mod 4 = 0) Or (bc Mod 5 = 0) Then

            If (bc Mod 2 = 0) Then
                way1 = bear(bc / 2)
            End If
            If (bc Mod 3 = 0) Or (bc Mod 4 = 0) Then
                way2 = bear((bc Mod 10) * ((bc Mod 100) / 10))
            End If
            If (bc Mod 5 = 0) Then
                way3 = bear(bc - 42)
            End If
            If (way1 Or way2 Or way3) Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: `bc` is the only `"bear counter"` i have and i am not storing any value on it except sending it to `bear()`. Because i only care **if it can reach to 42 or not**. So i don't care about returning numbers and sending them back into the `bear()`. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(upon further reflection, I can now see that the only problem is the line referenced below..)*

.. hang on, it looks like you can do this by just changing one line.  In the MOD 3 or 4 case, change this line:

```
way2 = bear((bc Mod 10) * ((bc Mod 100) / 10))
```

to these:

```
dim gb as Integer
gb = (bc Mod 10) * ((bc Mod 100) / 10)
If gb <= 0 then Return False
way2 = bear(bc - gb)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i noticed and fixed 42 but the only part i am confused about is `If gb = 0 Then Return False`. How will i send the first value into `bear()` on button click? (And i placed these 2 lines on top of the bear function, is it ok?)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But why did mod 3 or 4 case caused error? (except forgetting `bc-` part) Because when i tried `bear(bc-(bc Mod 10) * ((bc Mod 100) / 10))` it still caused error. since it can not be negative and zero won't cause a problem, i am confused.

Comment: ah sorry, i just figured out for 0. infinite loop. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing is that you're checking `bears(bearsToTake)` instead of `bears(bearsLeft-bearsToTake)`. I think you might be returning false prematurely as well, but I haven't checked, so don't quote me on that.

A solution in Python, for posterity. You don't necessarily need an extra "counter" value like the other answers suggest, but it is often good practice to use one. (I know you're not using Python, but it almost looks like psuedocode, and is thus I've found it easier to grok.)

This solution is almost identical to yours -- it just fixes the parameter from the taken bears to the total bears! bears bears bears.

```
>>> def checkBears(n):
...     if n == 42:
...         return True
...     elif n < 42:
...         return False
...     else:
...         if not n % 2 and checkBears(n/2):
...             return True
...         if (not n % 3 or not n % 4) and checkBears(n - n % 10 * (n%100)/10):
...             return True
...         if not n % 5 and checkBears(n - 42):
...             return True
...     return False
... 
>>> checkBears(250)
True
>>> checkBears(53)
False
>>> checkBears(42)
True
>>> checkBears(84)
True
```